# How to invoke authorize method in signalR server method from client?

Tags: c#, security, client, server, signalr

I am learning about signalR security in c#. For signalR there is lot for samples and documents available in google. using this i can understand the signalR concepts. i am trying to create console chat app using authorize. Without authorize attribute i can able to send and receive messages. while using "[authorize]" i am getting below error.

```
Error: InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=-2146233079
Message=There was an error invoking Hub method 'Test.DetermineLength'.
```

[image]

Server Program:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
        using (WebApp.Start<StartUp>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    [HubName("Test")]
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        [Authorize]
        public void DetermineLength(string message)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            string newMessage = string.Format(@"{0} has a length of: {1}", message, message.Length);
            Clients.All.ReceiveLength(newMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Program:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHubProxy _hub;
        string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
        var connection = new HubConnection(url);
        _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("Test");
        connection.Start().Wait();
        string line = null;
        while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            _hub.Invoke("DetermineLength", line).Wait();
            _hub.On("ReceiveLength", x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        }
     }
}
```

How to perform authorized communications between client and server using siganlR in c#. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

From the SignalR official documentation:

> SignalR provides the Authorize attribute to specify which users or roles have access to a hub or method. This attribute is located in the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR namespace. You apply the Authorize attribute to either a hub or particular methods in a hub. When you apply the Authorize attribute to a hub class, the specified authorization requirement is applied to all of the methods in the hub. This topic provides examples of the different types of authorization requirements that you can apply. Without the Authorize attribute, a connected client can access any public method on the hub.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

Who do you want to authorize that method for? Do you have user defined roles? 
You cannot use the method with the `Authorize` attribute because you don't have any users in your application.

Try defining some roles and see if it works.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer. it helps me to understand the concept. Can you tell how to define user in client side. i have tried i am getting context.user as null value.

Comment: You define roles in the context of a larger application, with registration and login. To do this, you should either implement the Asp.Net Identity interfaces, or create your own identity.

Comment: This is a good place for you to start researching identity and authentication in .NET (most examples are for ASP.NET). You can also try
[link](www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com)